# Android App crashes on Emulator but Android Studio doesn't make any problems

Tags: android, memory, crash

I planned to develop a Memory Game for Android, but already this Code crashes on the Emulator: 
Is it possible to use an ImageView Array for this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Random random1;
Random random2;
ImageView iv[] = {(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1), (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic2), (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic3), (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic4),
                  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic5), (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic6),
                  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic7),
                  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic8),
                  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic9),
                  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic10),
                   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic11),
                    (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic12),
                   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic13),
                   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic14)};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final int random_zahl_1 = random1.nextInt(13) + 1;
    final int random_zahl_2 = random2.nextInt(13) + 1;
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            iv[random_zahl_1].setImageResource(R.drawable.i1);
            iv[random_zahl_2].setImageResource(R.drawable.i2);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: kindly post your error message too

Comment: I only get the error: "Memory keeps stopping" on the Emulator. In Android Studio I haven't got any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `findViewById` in an activity before its content view is set. Try moving your array initialization into `onCreate`, after setting the content view.

Also, you need to initialize the `Random` objects before calling `.nextInt()` on them.

Comment: You need to provide more information then. You say that you don't see any errors when running in Android Studio -- are you looking at logcat? Do you see your activity starting in the logs? You should be able to add logs at strategic points in your `onCreate` to see where the issue is occurring.

Also, "memory keeps stopping" is not an Android error log I've ever seen. If the application is truly crashing, it should spit out an exception in the logs (or an ANR trace). Can you post that in your question?

Comment: I just noticed that your two random objects are never initialized. I'll add that to my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you, now it works, I forgot to write Random random1 = NEW RANDOM().